# Python - Bad CPU Type in Executable

Tags: python, macos, macos-catalina

I updated yesterday to MacOS 10.15 and when trying to launch python from the terminal I am getting a "bad cpu in executable" error. Is anybody else facing the same issue and is there a solution?

Comment: I bet that your Python executable is 32-bit, but [macOS Catalina dropped support for 32-bit executables](https://www.theverge.com/2019/10/12/20908567/apple-macos-catalina-breaking-apps-32-bit-support-how-to-prepare-avoid-update), so code written for the 32-bit architecture is now literally unsupported. If that's the case, almost nothing can be done about it, unfortunately (except installing a 64-bit Python interpreter, that is).

Comment: Did you install a 3rd-party Python in place of the version that comes with MacOS? Apple should have updated the built-in version to be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem with bash. You must to switch to zsh.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050